# 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend'

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pip, pipenv, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to use Facebook prophet for a project. The problem is that when I try to use it I have an error :

`'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend'`

when I initialize the prophet

```
from prophet import Prophet
m = Prophet()
```

I have installed prophet and pystan 1.19.1.1 using a pipenv. Here is my Pipfile

```
numpy = "~=1.20.2"
pystan = "~=2.19.1.1"
prophet = "~=1.0.1"
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong? The strangest part is that when I make test on a jupyter notebook I don't get this problem (in that case I just used pip to install prophet)

By the way I'm on IntelliJ since I also use java in my project

Answer (score 1):

This method works for me :
Creating new environment and use `conda install -c conda-forge prophet` in cmd

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on my windows machine while working with Prophet.
Setting the environment variable pointing to 'CMDSTAN' directory fixed it.

```
import os
os.environ['CMDSTAN'] = "C:/Anaconda/Anaconda3/envs/test_conda_env/Library/bin/cmdstan"

from prophet import Prophet
m = Prophet()
```

For me cmdstan was installed in /Library/bin/cmdstan, within my conda environment.